# Phonegap / Pushwoosh / Android - push notifications not working

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I'm working on getting push notifications to work using PhoneGap and Android. Pushwoosh seems to be a few steps ahead of Urban AirShip but I seem to be falling over on one of the last hurdles and hope someone can help. I have a few questions:

1) My application reports "Status code 210 - Application unknown" when I try to register a device token. I'm guessing that it's due to one of the parameters here:

pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "5976xxxx0902", appid : "Pxxxx9-Fxxx1" } ....

The x's are not real values - the rest is but I am confident that:

- The appid is what Pushwoods calls an "Application code" for my application (is that the same thing?)
- The project id is what google API console has in it's URL

So - why doesn't the Pushwoosh server recognise this?

2) How can you figure out on Pushwoosh how many device tokens have been registered

Thanks

Comment: Is the pushwoosh app configured for Android GCM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check pushwoosh appid carefully. It has format XXXXX-XXXXX (5 alphanumeric symbols, dash then 5 alphanumeric symbols again). It seems you have one additional letter in the first part of appid.

Comment: can u tell me, how to get the pushwhoosh app id??